# Dynamic Name Routing / Dynamic Route Matching in VueJS

Tags: image, vue.js, hyperlink, routes, dynamic-routing

I have some products that are being iterated over and being displayed. I'd like to use the images of the products as links to the specific page of each individual product. I want each product page to pull from the same template, substituting the props with the appropriate product details.

An example url for a product would be something like: `/shop/product/name-of-product`

Here is the relevant code:

```html
<template>
    <div class="p-avaible" v-for="item in avaibleProducts" :key="item.name">
        <router-link :to={ name: 'avaibleProducts' , params: { id: 1 }}>
            <img :key="item.image" :src="item.image">
        </router-link>
        <div class="p-name">{{ item.name }}</div>
        <div class="p-price">€{{ item.price }}</div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          cart: [],
          avaibleProducts: [
            {
              name: "PLASTIC BAGS 3-PACK v1",
              price: 0.33,
              image: require('@/assets/plastic-bag-pack.jpg'),
              description: 'First version plastic bags pack containing 3 HQ assets. Make sure to get yours today.',
              id: 1
            },
            {
              name: "VINYL TEXTURES 2-PACK v1",
              price: 0.22,
              image: require('@/assets/vinyl-texture-pack.jpg'),
              description: 'First version vinyl texture pack containing 2 HQ assets. Make sure to get yours today.',
              id: 2
            },
            {
              name: "STICKER PACK 6-PACK v1",
              price: 0.66,
              image: require('@/assets/sticker-bag-pack.jpg'),
              description: 'First version sticker bag pack containing 6 HQ assets. Make sure to get yours today.',
              id: 3
            }
          ],
        };
      }
    };
</script>
```

### Router/Index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Shop from '../views/Shop.vue'
import Product from '../views/Product'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/shop',
    name: 'Shop',
    component: Shop
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id',
    name: Product,
    component: Product
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Please modify your question by including the relevant pieces of code in the question, rather than through screenshots. Please refer to ['How do I ask a good question?'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before continuing

Comment: Give the Vue docs section on dynamic routes a good read, it will explain exactly what you're looking for. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: Ive checked, however I do not understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey :)) first you must add a **unique** **property** to your product list like a uuid or anything, also you can use ***id*** property but its not a good method

---

### step 1:

you must add uuid propery to your product object :

```
{
      name: 'PLASTIC BAGS 3-PACK v1',
      price: 0.33,
      image: require('@/assets/plastic-bag-pack.jpg'),
      description:
        'First version plastic bags pack containing 3 HQ assets. Make sure to get yours today.',
      id: 1,
      uuid: 'prd-001' // pay attention to this line 
    },
```

### step 2:

you need to create an **computed** propery

```
computed: {
  showProduct() {
    const id = this.$route.params.id;
    const product = this.avaibleProducts.find((p) => p.uuid == id);
    return product;
  },
```

### step 3:

and in your template you can access it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{ showProduct.name }} - {{ showProduct.price }} <!-- and etc ... {{ showProduct.image }}  --></li>
</ul>
```

---

### step 4:

you can load single product in this route:

```
/product/prd-001
```

the above route return your first product in your available products state

### step 5:

change your this line in your ***Router/Index.js*** file

---

**`name: Product`**

and put it in single quotation like this :

**`name: 'Product'`**

and change your router-link like this :

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'Product' , params:{ id: product.uuid }}">{{ product.name}}</router-link>
```

**well done!**

Comment: This all looks great, thanks. However Im not sure how to write the router-link tag. Could you give me an example of router.js and the router-link tag? Thanks you very much.

Comment: change your this line in your Router/Index.js file => name: Product  and put it in single quotation like this => name: 'Product' and change your router-link like this => <router-link :to="{name: 'Product' , params:{ id: product.uuid }}">{{ product.name}}</router-link>

Comment: Whenever I use router-link with params in my loop displaying the products they disappear from actual page.

Comment: Not in node.js console, however in browser console it throws error about the uuid, that its not defined. And 9 more errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one important part in your router `index.js` file. You need to enable prop passing in the `Product` components

### Router/Index.js

```js
{
  path: '/product/:id',
  name: Product,
  component: Product,
  props: true
}
```

Now you can actually pass props to your routes via a `<router-link>` element.

Now all you have to do is pass the appropriate props to the component. You can do this by emulating an API call on the component's `created()` hook.

I recommend you make a `JSON` file that you put somewhere in your `src` directory with all the details for the products. Instead of importing your image via webpack, just do it statically by putting the images in `public/images`.

You then need to make sure that the `id` is a unique URL-valid string if you want to use it as the param in the URL as you specified. It would look something like this:

`@/assets/json/productList.json`:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "plastic-bag",
        "name": "PLASTIC BAGS 3-PACK v1",
        "price": 0.33,
        "image": "/images/products/1.jpg",
        "description": "First version plastic bags pack containing 3 HQ assets. Make sure to get yours today."
    },
    ....
]
```

Then in your `Product.vue` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="product.image" alt="">
    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
    <pre>${{ product.price }} USD</pre>
    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import products from "@/assets/json/productList.json";

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          product: null;
        };
      },
      created() {
        this.setProduct();
      },
      methods: {
        setProduct() {
          const currentProject = products.find(project => project.id === this.$route.params.id); // Find project via the route id param
          this.product = currentProject;
        }
      }
    };
</script>
```